# Get raw data bytes of a constant float value using #define in C

Tags: c

I am trying to retrieve the raw data bytes from a constant float in C.  This is being done to create a readable constant byte array.  This can be seen below.

```
    #define FLOAT_TO_BYTES(value) \
        (uint8_t)(value),       (uint8_t)(value << 8), \
        (uint8_t)(value << 16), (uint8_t)(value << 24)

    const uint8_t byteArray[] = {
         FLOAT_TO_BYTES(11.4)
    };
```

The problem is that I cannot use pointers or any sort of a code block. I know the above doesn't work because you cannot shift a float value.  I have tried using unions but cannot get that to work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you really want the preprocessor to calculate those bytes for you, or is it enough that you get access to your float as an array of `unsigned char`s? If the latter, how about something like `const double x = 11.4; const unsigned char *byteArray = (unsigned char *) (&x);`? Or do you want the `sizeof(bytearray)` also to be `sizeof(double)`?

Comment: Please pick one language only. C and C++ are different languages and the answer can differ depending on which you are actually coding in.

Comment: I need the preprocessor to calculate the bytes because in actual implementation the byteArray is a couple of KB large and therefore has to be a const uint8_t array.

Comment: Why not overlay the "couple of KB large" `uint8_t` array with a "couple of KB large"/4 `float` array as a `union` and then provide the initialization as { 11.4f, 42.0f, 3.14159f, ...}`?

Comment: It is unclear, does the source code need to start with `float`s like `11.4f, 42.0f, 3.14159f` or _bytes_ `0x66, 0x66, 0x36, 0x41, `?

Comment: @chux: You can overlay an "array of `union`s", but not use a "`union` of arrays"

Comment: @Drew: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. Why not just have a const array of floats, and use appropriate `(unsigned char *)` casts when you need access to that data on the byte level? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @FreekWiedijk because the byteArray is an array that is KB large and there is no processing of the array and it is just sent to another device so I wouldn't know when and where to put the bytes of the float...

Comment: @Drew: But but but... The size of the data in memory will be exactly the same! And there will be no more or less processing with _this_ approach that with what you are trying. I mean, do: `const float floatArray[] = { 11.4 };` and then `#define byteArray ((unsigned char *) floatArray)`. And then use `byteArray[...]` to access the bytes and send them.

Comment: @FreekWiedijk Sorry you are correct that would work.  However I did not explain that the byteArray has only a few floats scattered out through it and mainly consists of uint16_t and uint8_t data types.

Comment: @Drew: I see. Those floats might not even be aligned then. Hmmm, difficult...

Comment: @drew Rather than post important restrictions in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862038/get-raw-data-bytes-of-a-constant-float-value-using-define-in-c#comment70909413_41862038), append that information to your post.   Adding more example data would help too.  This will help attract UVs, rather than DVs.

Comment: @drew Is the `float` data on multiple of 4 boundaries or potentially on unaligned ones?

Comment: @Drew: Are you using GCC? I mean, is it useful to try to accomplish what you want using GCC extensions?

Comment: @chux The float is potentially on unaligned boundaries.

Comment: @FreekWiedijk No I am not able to use GCC or the extensions sadly...

Comment: Suggest editing post to include important info of your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can get the bytes with a union:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union float_bytes{
    float f; 
    char  b[sizeof(float)];
};

int main()
{
    union float_bytes fb = { 1.1 };
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(float);i++)
        printf("%hhx\n", fb.b[i]);

}
```

You can also simply just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float f = 1.1;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(float);i++)
        printf("%hhx\n", ((char*)&f)[i]);

}
```

Inspecting anything via a character pointer is always allowed.

If you really want to, you can put the cast to a (char*) into a macro
and pass in a float pointer or you can create a compound literal temporary in the macro so as to avoid an explicit float variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FLOAT_BYTES(Float) ((char*)(&(float){Float}))
int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(float);i++)
        printf("%hhx\n", FLOAT_BYTES(1.1)[i]);
}
```

(The lifetime of a compound literal is that of its nearest enclosing block.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use byte operations on `float`s, because they are not standarized.

How can it be done? **NOTE:** All methods below assume that `float` is 32 bit wide.

Pointer

```
#define FLOAT_TO_BYTES(value) (*((unsigned char *) value)), (*(((unsigned char *) value) + 1)), (*(((unsigned char *) value) + 2)), (*(((unsigned char *) value) + 3))
```

Union

```
typedef union
{
  float f;
  unsigned char chars[4];
} __attribute__ ((packed)) floatunion;

// I am lazy:
#define FLOAT_TO_BYTES(value) FLOAT_TO_BYTES0 ((floatunion *) &value)
#define fLOAT_TO_BYTES0(value) value->chars[0], value->chars[1], value->chars[2], value->chars[3]
```

Comment: I'm not sure the pointer variant invokes undefined behaviour. However, the `union` variant is the explicitly allowed way for type-punning and the prefered approach. Not sure, though why you added the `packed` attribute. It is not standard, and unnecessary.

Comment: The `packed` attribute is based on my experience with OS development. It might be unnecessary.

Comment: And any memory referencing of `float`s should be in my opinion undefined

Comment: It is quite useless even for OS development. Better convert to/from `uintN_t` and shjift /mask for marshalling. leave optimisations to the compiler. Packed `struct`s are likely to be slower (much slower if the CPU does not support unaligned accesses like many ARMs) on normal accesses, while (de)serialisation typically is only done for load/store of data.

Comment: @Olaf I also code for ARM. GCC optimizes it into bit shifting stuff (fortunately :D)

Comment: Neither of those work when using a constant float value when calling the FLOAT_TO_BYTES(1.3).  It gives an error of cannot use '&' on a constant.

Comment: @Drew Are you sure this is possible for a constant? I think this **requires** memory access.

Comment: You should be using a temporary variable

Comment: @JakubKaszycki: That's not an optimisation, but actually slows down ever-day access just to "simplify" the reare times when you serialise the object. Write a set of marshalling or use a library like protobuf or it's small cousin nanopb to generate the code/structures.

Comment: That is what I am wondering.  I know it can be done using predefined constants but then that isn't terribly readable either and at that point most likely would just convert the float into a uint32_t using a post processing tool.  But that is a last resort.

Comment: @Drew: You can write a macro for that using gcc extensions. But I don't see much reason to use a macro anyway .

Comment: @Drew: To view raw bytes of a float constant, you need to have a pointer to it to convert it to a scalar integer type pointer. So it implies memory access. Literals **don't** have a memory location. I use GCC, the extensions probably compute the float's value at compile time. If you want a portable program, don't use them

Comment: @JakubKaszycki In C, _literals_ can have their address taken like `&"abc"` or `&((int [3]){1,2,3})`.  It does not require a GCC extension.   `123.4f` is not a _literal_ in C.  It is a _constant_, a _floating constant_.  _Constants_ do not necessarily have a memory location - which I think is more clear the intention of the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862038/get-raw-data-bytes-of-a-constant-float-value-using-define-in-c?noredirect=1#comment70908607_41862164).

Answer (score 0):

Use a *compound literal* of a `union`, available since C99.

Does not use pointers or shifts.  Code needs to specify which byte and order of the `float` desired.

```
#define FLOAT_TO_BYTE(float_value, index) \
    (( \
    (union { float f; uint8_t u8[sizeof (float)]; }) {(float_value)} \
    ).u8[(index)])

// size sensitive code - assume sizeof (float) == 4
#define FLOAT_TO_BYTES(float_value) \
    FLOAT_TO_BYTE((float_value), 0), FLOAT_TO_BYTE((float_value), 1), \
    FLOAT_TO_BYTE((float_value), 2), FLOAT_TO_BYTE((float_value), 3)

int main(void) {
  const uint8_t byteArray[] = { 
      42,
      FLOAT_TO_BYTE(11.4, 0),
      FLOAT_TO_BYTE(11.4, 1),
      FLOAT_TO_BYTE(11.4, 2),
      FLOAT_TO_BYTE(11.4, 3),
      42,
      FLOAT_TO_BYTES(11.4)
  };
  for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof byteArray; i++) {
    printf("%u %u\n", i, 1u*byteArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Output

```
0 42
1 102
2 102
3 54
4 65
5 42
6 102
7 102
8 54
9 65
```